# How to find HTML5 hidden objects in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I'm working with a HTML5 website which uses "hidden" property within its elements to hide objects in the screen.

For instance,

the visible "div" is structured as,

```
<div>
..
</div>
```

whereas the hidden object is structured as,

```
<div hidden>
..
</div>
```

So, how do I uniquely identify the  object from the  object since there is no property assigned to "hidden" here?

Comment: What do you want actually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `x-path` like `//div[not(@hidden)]` to find the visible elements.